# Display a component after a click($event) Angular 4

Tags: angular, mouseclick-event

I'm trying to create an event on a click button who fired another component, if you click again it reduce the component (a part of the displayed component is always visible)..
I know this could be done with [ngClass]='hidden' and everything in the same component but I am not sure whether its the best way in terms of modularity.
Thanks in advance

Here's my html:

```
<div class="daydetail">
     <h1>Detail of the day</h1>
     <button type="button" label="Click"(click)="display('my-displaychild')"></button>
     <div>{{my-displaychild}}</div>
</div>
```

Here's is my component:

```
import { DisplayChildComponent } from './displaychild.component';

export class AppliV2Component   { 


    display(vid:DisplayChildComponent) {
           console.log(DisplayChildComponent);
    }


 }
```

Comment: use ngIf directive

Comment: @Maximus thanks I didn't think of ngIf easy :) I ll try it thanks for you help

Comment: no problem, let me know how it goes

Comment: @Maximus how could you make a $event equal to ngIf ? Could you show me an exemple?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think you should keep it simple with the  use of `*ngIf` and you can pass in the boolean value to the child component to hide only the part you want using the `@Input` decorator

1.parent HTML

```html
<div class="daydetail">
     <h1>Detail of the day</h1>
     <button type="button" label="Click" (click)="toggleChild()"></button>
     <div>
         <child-component [showMePartially]="showVar"></child-component>
     </div>
</div>
```

2.parent component

```ts
export class AppliV2Component {
    showVar: boolean = true;

    toggleChild(){
        this.showVar = !this.showVar;
    }
 }
```

3.child component

```ts
export class ChildComponent {
    @Input() showMePartially: boolean;

    // don't forget to import Input from '@angular/core'
}
```

4.child HTML

```html
<div>
    <h1> this part is always visible</h1>
</div>

<div *ngIf="showMePartially">
    <h1> this part will be toggled by the parent component button</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: @EmileCantero great! but If you want to display only part of the child component I can update my answer to show you how you can do it

Comment: I just updated the answer now! hope with will help you :)

Comment: I my friend I've got a question according to the parent component:  Is it possible to trigger many variable to the child-component? Like for exemple :<div><child-component [showMePartially]="showVar" [showMeTotally]="fooVar"></child-component></div> ...thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have a api for Products. I've listed them.And user can add to cart this items.

```
<div>
  <ul class="list-group">
  <li *ngFor="let product of products" class="list-group-item">
    <button (click)="addToCart(product)" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary pull-right">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
      Add To Cart
    </button>
    <h5><strong>{{product.productName}}</strong></h5>
    <p> {{product.quantityPerUnit}}</p>
    <h6>{{product.unitPrice}}</h6>
  </li>
```

method is like this.

```
addToCart(product:Product){
this.addedProduct=product.productName;
this.notificationsService.success("Successfull",product.productName +" added to CART")
  }
```